# ItemsControl with Grid as template : add control to Grid

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 7.1 project (XAML).
I have a itemscontrol with a grid as template, bound to collection of data-elements, everything works okay. 
However, I have to add one extra Image to the Grid, which does not bind to the collection. Some kind of header image.

I have this code:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="ShipsGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!--<Image Source="/images/image.png" x:Name="SuperImage"/>-->

                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="ElementImage" Source="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:ShipItemsGridControl>
```

If I uncomment the Image in ItemsPanelTemplate (x:Name SuperImage), I get the following error: Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.

I have tried several things, but I can't manage to get it working. Of course I can add it to the itemtemplate and only make it visible in first item, but that is very, very ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just stacking the `Image` on top of your `ItemsControl` by placing both in a parent panel that allows overlapping controls, such as a `Grid` or a `Canvas`?

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ... />
    <Image Source="/images/image.png"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Margin="5,5,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

In the code sample I just set a margin of 5 for both the Top and the Left margins, but you will probably need to mess with that a bit to line the Image up with your first Grid cell.

Also if you need to dynamically set the height/width of the image to make it the same size as your Grid cell, you can bind the `Height` and `Width` properties of the Image to the ItemsControl's ActualHeight/ActualWidth and use a Converter to figure out 1/10th of that size (I have a [MathConverter on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/tag/math-converter/) which would make this easy)

The only other alternative I could think of would be to add it in the code-behind after the items have been generated

```
void MyItemsControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += 
        ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == 
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // Remove ItemContainerGenerator event
        MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
            -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;

        // Add Image to ItemsControl here
    }
}
```

This isn't really ideal though, and I would do my best to simply place the Image on top of the ItemsControl first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A parent container is not an option, because the image has to be in on of the 10 columns / rows defined in the Grid. How can I add it in code-behind? Which event should I bind to? Not ideal, but indeed I think last option.

Comment: @Boland Depending on your type of parent container, you can stack your objects so the Image is on top of your ItemsControl. Both a `Grid` and a `Canvas` will allow child objects to be "stacked" on top of each other. By default the last child added is on top, however you can also use `Canvas.ZIndex` to manipulate which object is on top. If I did go the other route, I'd just use the `Loaded` event to attach some code to the `ItemContainerGenerator` that would add the final item once it's finished generating all the items.

Comment: If I do it your way (thus Image outside of ItemsControl) I have to redeclare all row and column definitions, right? I have 10 rows and 10 columns, so that would be a lot of extra XAML.

Comment: @Boland No, you just need to position the Image using Margins or `Canvas.Left`/`Canvas.Top`. I'll update the example code in my answer...

Comment: And sorry, I don't know how to attach code to the ItemContainerGenerator? I only can find methods to retrieve indices / objects in the itemscontrol. No event whatsoever to add some control...

Comment: I have tried to attach to Loaded event and retrieve one item by ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0), but that is null.... Hope you can point me in right direction!

Comment: @Boland I updated my answer to include a code sample. I really wouldn't recommend going that route though, and the ideal solution would be to simply place the Image on top of the ItemsControl

Comment: I have done it as you proposed, thus placing image outside grid. Only disadvantages is double declaration of column- and rowdefinitions, but no code behind. I need the image to be exactly in the grid, the user can move the item. In drag-event I move the image through the grid. It works!