# Changing combobox item background color within wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, mvvm

I have a wpf application in which I need to customize a combobox to make it editable.

```
public class AutoCompleteFacturation: ComboBox 
{
    List<vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique> liste = new List<vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique>();
    // [...]
    ItemsSource = NewDataSource;
    liste = NewDataSource.ToList<vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique>();
    ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)base.Items[0];
    item.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.AliceBlue;
}
```

I need to change the background of the first item `ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)base.Items[0];` ==> I get an exception indicates that the cast of `vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique` to `ComboBoxItem` is not possible.

So How can I fix this to coloriate the first item of the combobox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item you're getting is the one that is bound using `DataSource` (here of type `vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique`).

What you need is `ComboBoxItem`, which is a container. To get it, use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)` or `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750552(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: +1 because using the `ItemContainerGenerator` is the correct way to get the UI object associated with the bound data object :) That said, I think a Trigger or Converter would be easier in this specific case

Comment: @Arie I get null values   `ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
            ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(SelectedFiche);`

Comment: @LamloumiAfif You need to run that after the containers have been generated. There's a quick sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15388441/302677) if you want... basically you attach an event to the `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged`, and when the status changes to `ContainersGenerated` you remove the event handler and apply any customizations to the UI object. In your specific case though, you may want to investigate using Background Binding with a Converter

Answer (score 1):

You binded your `ComboBox` on your list.

So `Items` return a list of `vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique`

2 Possibilities :

`foreach (vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique fiche in liste)
    {
       ComboBoxItem i = new ComboBoxItem();
       i.Content = fiche.Text;
       i.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.AliceBlue;
       base.Items.Add(i);
    }`

Or wrap your `vue_fsign_fiche_signaletique` in a **View Model** and use a **IValueConverter**

Comment: Personally I prefer the `ItemsSource` binding to looping through the objects and manually creating a `ComboBoxItem` for each one. I'd recommend implementing a Trigger or a Background Binding + Converter though.